# StAX Writer Implementation for C/C++

Tags: c++, c, xml, stax

Are there any other STaX Writer implementation for C/C++ except libxml2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[LLamaXML](http://llamaxml.berlios.de/)

Its one of the few C++ pull parsers.

Answer (score 1):

The article about [STaX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/StAX) in Wikipedia mentiones [Expat](http://expat.sourceforge.net/) in the list of implementations.

Comment: Expat implement only parser :(

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the [Genx](http://www.tbray.org/ongoing/When/200x/2004/02/20/GenxStatus) library.

Answer (score 0):

- Qt has [QXmlStreamWriter](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qxmlstreamwriter.html) and [QXmlStreamReader](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qxmlstreamreader.html)
- [Irrlicht Engine](http://irrlicht.sourceforge.net/) contain [IXMLWriter](http://irrlicht.sourceforge.net/docu/classirr_1_1io_1_1_i_x_m_l_writer.html) that use StAX model