# Is there native XmlReader equvalent API in C++ on Windows?

Tags: c++, xml, msxml

On Linux platforms I like [libxml2 reader API](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-xmlreader.html#xmlTextReaderRead) which is based on C#'s [XmlReader::Read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.read.aspx) and reads one node/attribute at a time without actually building DOM tree.

Now, I'm in need of native Windows C++ XML parsing library. MSXML instantly comes to mind.
Is there MSXML API allowing to read one node at a time, without building DOM or processing the whole document in SAX style?

Comment: libxml2 works on Windows. Is there a reason to not want that?

Comment: It works while eating my intestines. I'm tired of compiling it with so many quirks and decided to use something native wrapped in my own platform independent code.

Comment: Check list of StAX parsers and writers in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1693523/stax-writer-implementation-for-c-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at another Microsoft's XML parser [XmlLite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163436.aspx):

> a non-cached, forward-only parser (that delivers a pull programming model) and a non-cached, forward-only XML generator

Answer (score -2):

I use tinyxml:
http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxml/

> TinyXML is a simple, small, minimal, C++ XML parser that can be easily
>   integrating into other programs. It reads XML and creates C++ objects
>   representing the XML document. The objects can be manipulated,
>   changed, and saved again as XML

/mspoerr

Comment: TinyXML completely parses the complete document first. You should've read the question better.